# How to pragramatically change a dropdownlist to another field's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a dropdownlist with a list of countries (all countries)

```html
<select id="Country" onchange="country();">
  <option id="3">Japan</option>
  <option id="4">Canada</option>
  <option id="5">France</option>
  <option id="6">Peru</option>
</select>
```

I have the form in a modal that i want get country value from.

```
<input id="seachcountry" type="text" class="form-control" name="country">
```

I have written a JQuery line to get the value from the modal form to the page fields, everything works great but the country select fields are not changing the value.

```
$("#seachcountry").val($("#modalform").val()).trigger("chang‌e");
```

thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: $("#seachcountry").val($("#modalform").val()).trigger("change");

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding code to the comment section

Comment: where is the #pageform and #modalform elements?

Comment: make sure you have unique ids on your selects

Comment: your select and input same id , it maybe confused

Comment: Hi, yes, thank you, i have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This will work for you:**

Just inject the `value` of the `<input>` to `<select>`.

I have created a snippet for you.

```js
var Tval = $('#seachcountry').val();

$('#Country').val(Tval);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Country" onchange="country();">
  <option id="3">Japan</option>
  <option id="4">Canada</option>
  <option id="5">France</option>
  <option id="6">Peru</option>
</select>

<input id="seachcountry" type="text" class="form-control" name="country" value="France">
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing value in any select you just need send exist value from this select. In your select options have only ids, but not have `value` attribute. So if you add `value` equal to `id` to change value in the your form to "France" need run following:

```
$("#selectId").val(5)
```

Instead of `5` you can obtain value from any other field or else.

If you want set your value to input field when changed in select, you need attach listener that will do all work. It will looks like this:

```
$("#selectId").on("change", function(){
     $("#inputFieldId").val($(this).find(":selected").text());
})
```

This will set displayed value to select, to set real value just write instead `$(this).find(":selected").text()` this `$(this).val()`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but i only have "France" in my input field, i need to change the select field to "France"

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function country() {
    $("#seachcountry").val($(this).val());
}
```